# Maximizing the sum of a decreasing function over a separated set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, nonlinear-optimization

Fix $d>0$.  Let $f:[0,\infty)\to(0,\infty)$ be a decreasing function of $x$ for $x\geq d$.  Let $S_d\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ represent a set of points containing the origin such that the (Euclidean) distance between each pair of points is at least $d$.  I want to compute or upper bound the quantity
$$\max_{S_d} \sum_{x_i\in S_d} f(\|x_i\|_2),$$
where the maximum is taken over all possible $S_d$.
I am particularly interested in the case where $f(x)=p(x)\exp(-x^2/\sigma)$ for some fixed $\sigma>0$ and some fixed polynomial $p$.  I would also be happy with values or (non-asymptotic) upper bounds when $n=2$.  Furthermore, it would be interesting to know more about $S_d$.  For instance, will it differ from a hexagonal lattice of equilateral triangles?

Here is the stack exchange post for the same question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1976474/maximizing-the-sum-of-a-decreasing-function-over-a-separated-set

Comment: Not quite clear: $f$ is a function of one real variable, then what is $f(x_i)$, given that $x_i\in S_d\subset\mathbb{R}^n$?